# Write the same value to all rows with the same ID

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-pig, user-defined-functions

I'm looking for a way to write the same value to all the records with the same ID. I load this table in HDFS environment using Apache Pig and the python code is needed only for this transformation (as a UDF) Here is an example:

```html
    ID   ; firstname ; lastname
   1234    Alex        Jones
   1234    Frank       na
   1234    Maria       na
```

What I need is to assign the lastname (Jones) to everyone with the same ID. I know how to do this with pandas, but the problem for me is that I have to do this without using any packages. 
Any suggestions are appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Is this a dictionary? A string?

Comment: what data type is it ?

Comment: It is a table with strings as values. @MichaelBianconi

Comment: @Y.C.T A table implemented in what?

Comment: A table I load in HDFS environment using Apache Pig and the python code is needed only for this transformation (as a UDF). @MichaelBianconi

Comment: This would be useful information to include in your post.

Comment: Is it just one name "Jones" or you will have others as well?

Comment: @VK_217 this is just an example, there are thousands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter the ID,lastname combination then Distinct the id, lastname into a relation and join it with the original relation then finally generate the required columns. 
Assuming data is loaded into relation A, then

```
B = FILTER A BY (lastname != 'na');
C = FOREACH B GENERATE ID,lastname;
D = DISTINCT C;
E = JOIN A BY ID,D BY ID;
F = FOREACH E GENERATE A.ID,A.firstname,D.lastname;
DUMP F;
```

Relation D will have `1234,Jones` because you filter 'na's and then distinct.Then after the join relation E will look like

```
1234    Alex     Jones    1234    Jones
1234    Frank    na       1234    Jones
1234    Maria    na       1234    Jones
```

From the above you then get the first two columns from relation A and last column from relation D.Finally F will have

```
1234    Alex    Jones
1234    Frank   Jones
1234    Maria   Jones
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I think it will work. Just from curiosity can this transformation be even written as a Python UDF implemented in Pig?

Comment: Yes, you can write a Python UDF to achieve the same result.